# All products in a product_tag are not showing up on collection page

Tags: shopify

The issue is odd- on a collection page where we show all products separated by their product types, the page only shows around 80% of the total. There is no limit hit on any page yet, and when we click through to a product_type page, all products are clearly there.

Here's the .liquid theme file we are using now-

```
{% if collection.handle %}
  <!-- basic collection -->
  <!-- sorting by product type within collection (with titles) -->
  {% assign sorted_by_type = collection.all.products | sort: 'type' %}

  {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
  <div class="products clearfix collection">
      {% assign the_type = product_type %}
      <h2>{{ the_type | link_to_type }}</h2>
      {% paginate collections.all.products by 2000 %}
        {% for product in collections.all.products %}
          {% if product.type == the_type %}
            {% include 'product-loop' %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endpaginate %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% else %}
  <!-- vendor -->
  {% assign image_name = collection.title | handleize | append: '.jpg' %}
  <div class="banner my-backstretch" data-vendorname="{{ collection.title | handleize }}" data-src="{{ image_name | asset_url }}"></div>

  <!-- sorting by product type within vendor (with titles) -->
  {% assign sorted_by_type = collection.products | sort: 'type' %}

  {% for product_type in collection.all_types %}
  <div class="products clearfix collection">
      {% assign the_type = product_type %}
      <h2>{{ the_type | link_to_type }}</h2>
      {% paginate collection.products by 2000 %}
        {% for product in collection.products %}
          {% if product.type == the_type %}
        {% include 'product-loop' %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endpaginate %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Any help or assistance pinpointing this error would be great! Not super familiar with Shopify yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're telling it to paginate by 2000 products, you're still going to be limited to 50.

[See here in the Shopify docs](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/how-do-i-show-more-products-on-my-collection-pages) for more info:

> ```
> {% paginate collection.products by 9 %}
> ```
>
> In the above example, the number is 9 but in your theme, that number could be 6 or 12, or anything else that is **smaller or equal to 50**. This number corresponds to the number of products showcased per page.
>
> Edit that number to increase or decrease the number of products shown per page. **Do not ever paginate by more than 50**.